# Red light facing forwards?

Tags: safety, headlights

I was criticized for having a blinking red light facing forwards on my handlebars (in addition to a White headlight). What is wrong with this? It was nighttime in Manhattan. Isn't more always better when it comes to being seen?

**THANK YOU FOR THE ANSWERS, my mistake has been corrected. Best wishes to you all.**

Comment: While A light might be perceived as better than NO light, having the WRONG light is of limited value.   Car drivers are simple machines and can't be expected to perceive you correctly if you're giving bad information, and giving the driver cognitive overload.   Do it right, get home alive.

Comment: Personally I run more rear (red) lights than front (white) lights because a cyclist can't tell if their rear goes out.   Did you have a red light facing backwards, as well?

Comment: I nearly rode into an oncoming cyclist who had a bright red light on the front on a bike path. He had a white light as well but it was feeble - dimmer than the reflection of my front light off common reflective backpacks. Dodging onto a bumpy verge at 20mph in the dark I was lucky not to do myself an injury. Add white or yellow if you want more front lights.

Comment: Please don't do this!  Can you imagine the carnage if people started modifying their cars in this way?  A red light is almost universally understood to mark the rear of a vehicle (and therefore that the vehicle is moving **away** from the observer).

Comment: Red light wavelength let the driver notice you from miles away from your rear. It is useless to put in front when you already have a front light. Unless you want some drivers to ramp you.

Comment: What is wrong with this? Look at every other vehicle on the road. Do they have red lights on the front? Other people have explained the very real safety problems with putting red lights on the front of a bike but, honestly, your question is very much like, "I decided to cycle on the other side of the road for a bit but I was criticized for it. What's wrong with it?"

Comment: And you're doing this in Manhattan of all places?! Out on a quiet country lane a completely inappropriately lighted bicycle might not be the worst thing you could do, but in busy urban traffic it's tantamount to suicide. Why would you want to confuse the drivers around you? I would also expect the first NYPD cop that sees you to hand you a well-deserved ticket for it.

Comment: In the Netherlands it's illegal to drive with a non-white light up front and a non-red light at the back. Orange is an iffy case, but the rest is forbidden. I suspect the same rule applies in many other countries.

Comment: @Mast isn't it also illegal in NL for the lights to be flashing?

Comment: @phoog Yes, that's forbidden on every vehicle. Only emergency vehicles are allowed to carry flashing lights, although extra-ordinary vehicles are allowed to carry flashing yellow lights. Bicycles are never allowed flashing lights.

Comment: A bit of online searching suggests that it's not actually illegal to have red lights facing forward, or white backward, even on a car: http://www.safeny.ny.gov/equi-vt.htm for example. Or maybe I just haven't stumbled across the relevant prohibition. But as is often the case, "not illegal" does not mean "is a good idea".

Comment: @Móż, 375.2(c) from your link: "No lamp shall be used on a motor vehicle having a light source greater than thirty-two candle power, unless such lamp is approved by the commissioner as provided by this section", and 375.4: "No headlamp shall be used upon any motor vehicle...operated upon the public highways of this state, unless such lamp is approved by the commissioner..."

Comment: @Mark you'll note that NY distinguishes between "motor vehicle" and "bicycle" in those rules. And any restriction on colour would come from the commissioner, not directly from the rules, in any case. What I was looking for was the usual bald "no vehicle shall have a red light facing forward, or a white light to the rear" (and note "vehicle" not "motor vehicle").

Comment: Only do this if you're cycling backwards.

Answer (score 68):

No. You should always ride with a white light facing forward and a red light facing backwards. If you want additional illumination, you can add multiple white/red lights in the appropriate direction. Amber/yellow lights can be used facing any direction for additional visibility.

The first reason is that [it's the law](http://www.safeny.ny.gov/bike-vt.htm):

> (a) Every bicycle when in use during the period from one-half hour after sunset to one-half hour before sunrise shall be equipped with a lamp on the front which shall emit a white light visible during hours of darkness from a distance of at least five hundred feet to the front and with a red or amber light visible to the rear for three hundred feet. Effective July first, nineteen hundred seventy-six, at least one of these lights shall be visible for two hundred feet from each side.

More importantly for your safety though, the color of a light conveys a certain meaning. Drivers, pedestrians, and other cyclists associate the color red with a taillight and the color white with a headlight. If you put the wrong color facing the wrong direction, people may think you are traveling the opposite direction. Imagine a car is pulling out of a driveway and sees a red bike light flashing to their left. They may assume that means a bike is moving away from them on the left. If they then pull out of the driveway and you're really moving towards them, you could get hit.

Comment: And the driver who sees what seems to be a white light and a red light on the same vehicle has to spend time wondering what on earth that person is doing. I'd rather they spent that time looking out for me. A red light on the front of a bike is dangerous to _all_ road users, not just the person with the wrong light.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: There is a common situation where a white and red light would be seen in close proximity on a vehicle: a car traveling in reverse.  The key point, though, is that on wheeled vehicles a red light is used to indicate the rear (boats have red lights on the port side and green lights on the starboard side, but having green lights on a wheeled vehicle could be a bad idea).

Comment: @supercat A car in reverse is a great point. Doesn't quite apply in this situation because the red light was flashing, but the question could just as well have been about a steady red light.

Comment: @supercat In English countries, green flashing lights are restricted to doctors/medical people on urgent business.  Likewise Blue lights are reserved for the exclusive use of police on urgent business.   So normal vehicles can have white forward, red rear, and amber/yellow to the sides.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not sure which "English countries" you mean. In the UK, all of the emergency services use only blue flashing lights.

Comment: @DavidRicherby He's talking about doctors on emergency response, not emergency services.  See *The Road Vehicles Lighting Regulations 1989* [part 11(2)(m)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/regulation/11/made).

Comment: @WillVousden Gosh. I have never in my life seen such a thing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Neither have I!

Comment: @supercat Note that white reversing lights make a lot of sense, since they indicate that the vehicle is moving *toward* the observer, just like headlights.

Comment: @Criggie, in this "English country" (USA), the only flashing green light I've ever seen was on a private security vehicle, and that was because it's the only color that's not restricted for a specific purpose.

Comment: @mark perhaps I should have said "Commonwealth countries"  The USA diverged onto its own path centuries ago.

Answer (score 0):

**DOT 108**  forbids red lights on front of vehicles and on front sides ahead of the rear axle of the vehicle, except for emergency vehicles.

Comment: Welcome to the site - are you referring to a law in Manhattan or elsewhere ?

Comment: DOT is probably the US Dept of Transport. The OP might mean 49 CFR § 571.108, where CFR = the US Code of Federal Regulations. The thing is, the intro does not seem to describe it as applying to non-motorized bicycles (but IANAL).

Answer (score -4):

It's more because when a red light is shone, it implies to face an observer from either idle stance or from the same direction. But, if they were white, it'd imply onward, additive-to-impact velocities and state of impulse direction.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! We recommend that all new members take our [tour] to learn how the site works. In this case, your answer is not clear to me, so I recommend that you read [how to answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and the rest of the [help]. Then, please edit this post to make your meaning clear to others

Comment: Insofar as I can understand it at all, this seems to just duplicate the final paragraph of the existing answer.